# How to store values in session using React Native?

Tags: javascript, session, react-native, asyncstorage

I've set the location as session variable at user registration (`index.js`) using `AsyncStorage.setItem`. I am trying to access this session variable in `Profile.js`. But when i tried to print the session variable (location) nothing is getting.Following is my code.What wrong i'm doing? please help

**index.js**

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('location').then((location) =>{
            this.setState({ location: location })
        })
```

**Profile.js**

```
fetch('http://loaclhost/apps/requirement.php',{
        method:'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept':'application/json' ,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            location:this.state.location,   
        })
    }).then( () =>
    {

        response => response.json();
    AsyncStorage.getItem('location').then((location) => {
        this.setState({location: location})
    })

    render(){
            return(
            <Container>
             <View>
            <TextInput 
        value={this.state.loctaion} />
             </View>
            </Container>
        );
    }
```

Comment: You just set key for your `Asyncstorage` but not set the value

Comment: What change do i need to make? Can you give the code?

Comment: oke, but first from where you got the `location` value before you set to your `Asyncstorage` ? can you change your question ?

Comment: Actually location is taken as user input at the time of registration.My purpose is to display profile details for each user based on their location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you,

**index.js**

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('location_key', 'location_value').then((location) =>{
    this.setState({ location: location })
})
```

**Profile.js**

```
var getLocation = function(){
    return AsyncStorage.getItem('location_key')
}

var fetchCall = function(location){
    return fetch('http://loaclhost/apps/requirement.php',{
        method:'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept':'application/json' ,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            location: location, //Resolved location
        })
    })
}


function fetchRequest(){

    getLocation()
    .then(fetchCall)
    .then((response) => {
        //Response handling
    })
}
```

Comment: I've tried this. But in `profile.js` when i consoled i got error that `getItem` is not a function. How do i check whether session is set or not?

Comment: AsyncStorage.getAllKeys().then((keys) => {
        console.log("All Key")
        console.log(keys)
      })

Comment: I can't access the session variable on `profile.js`. But on the same page (`index.js`) `AsyncStorage.setItem` and  `AsyncStoage.getItem ` is working. Not working in diffenernt page.

Comment: Can you add that Piece of code, so we can figure out what's wrong with it

Comment: `AsyncStorage.getItem('key_location').then((value) => 
 console.log(value));` This is my code in `profile.js` for getting session. When i use this code in`index.js` where i set session i get value , but not working in `profile.js`

Comment: i'm getting this error `reactNative2.default.getItem is not a function`

Comment: Make sure that your importing correctly,  import React from 'react';
import ReactNative from 'react-native'; import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native'.

Comment: I fixed this issue..Can i use `AsyncStorage.multiget` for getting more than one variable?

Comment: Yes you can use. If my answer helped you then do Accept the answer by clicking right marked below my answer.